# How to set the Video recording time limit in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to set the time limit for a video recording in the iPhone? I know the maximum limit is 10 minutes. But I want to reduce it to 5 minutes. If it is possible how can it be done?

Comment: Yes it is related to programming. He's just not asked his question very informatively.

Answer (score 18):

You need to set the `videoMaxiumDuration` property on `UIImagePickerController` after configuring it for video recording.

The value is an `NSTimeInterval` which is specified in seconds, so you'll want to set it to 300 seconds if you want 5 mins of video.

Comment: If you've been able to setup a UIImagePickerController in video recording mode, you should be able to figure out how to set the duration. Read the documentation for UIImagePickerController and come back.

Answer (score 8):

You can set video Recording limitations using

```
[imgPickerCtrl setVideoMaximumDuration:30.0f];
```

Here it will limit video recording upto 30seconds also it will alert you when you select the video from library that it is beyond the limit and it will crop it automatically.

Comment: what if i want to remove alert that video limit exceed?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
let MAX_VIDEO_DURATION = 30.0 // note the .0, must be double, move this at the top of your class preferrebly
picker.videoMaximumDuration = NSTimeInterval(MAX_VIDEO_DURATION)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 and Higher Version of Swift**

Its Really Simple as you think.

```
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = TimeInterval(30.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `swift5`

```
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 14
```

You also can set other properties like in bellow code...

```
     if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
            imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = .off
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 14
            imagePicker.videoQuality = .typeIFrame960x540 
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .video
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true
           
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Camera not available
            print("Camera not avaiable")
        }
```